# What is the % CSS Color Attribute supposed to mean?

Tags: css, attributes

I have a client that has asked for the following color for the background of an element: PMS227 75%

What color is this? What is the 75% supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost certainly refers to the alpha channel, or opacity of the color. This would be a float between zero and one.

```
background-color: rgba(173, 0, 91, 0.75);
```

Demo:

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(173, 0, 91, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

PMS is a color standard for prints, created by [Pantone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone). I've shown the RGB equivalent above.

- [Chart](http://www.cal-print.com/InkColorChart.htm)

Comment: Thanks: I think you're right and I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The element you mentioned is not valid. However, a percent is valid in rgb/rgba. The R is for red, G for green, and B for blue, optionally the A is for alpha.

```
rgb(0, 0, 100%)
```

This would mean 100% blue.